# How can the compiler in C get the difference between the address of the first element of the array and the address of the whole array?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, mingw

Given this problem and I'm fully aware of the facts of :

1) The name of an array is a fixed pointer to the first element of it.

2) The name of a 2D matrix is the address of the first 1D array of it.

3) and the difference between x[i] and &x[i] in arithmetic operations (where i is a non negative integer).

The compiler is MinGW
How can the compiler in C get the difference between the address of the first element of the array and the address of the whole array although they hold the same numeric value ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ; 
    int *p  ; 
    for(p = &x[0] ; p < &x[0] + 1 ; p++) //Warning: comparison of distinct pointer types in this line of code 
        printf("%d\n",*p) ; 

    return 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: Post the code as is using the code formatter instead of an image

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking about the first element, or about element `i`.

Comment: `p &< x[0] + 1` look like a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry , this was another program . I've uploaded the right one now.

Comment: @ArdentCode I didn't write "work well" or `&<`. I wrote "nothing in common". But I already deleted that part when I noticed a 2D array.

Comment: Do not post the code as an image. You've done that twice now.

Comment: `&x[0]` is not an `int *`!!

Comment: @ArdentCode you should ask OP that, not some fictional commenter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning / comparing two different pointer types.

`x` has type `int [3][3]`, i.e. an array of size 3 of an array of size 3 of `int`.  From there, `x[0]` has type `int [3]`, i.e. array of size 3 of `int`.

Subsequently, `&x[0]` has type `int (*)[3]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of size 3 of `int`.  In contrast, `p` has type `int *`, i.e. pointer to `int`.  These are distinct types, which is why the compiler is giving you a warning.

The compiler parses expressions in more-or-less the manner I described, looking at the type of an object and seeing how the type of the resulting expression changes as each operator is applied.

Comment: But you forgot to answer "*How can the compiler in C get the difference between the address of the first element of the array and the address of the whole array although they hold the same numeric value?*"

Comment: @ArdentCoder: I think that is just a language problem and OP is not literally asking how the difference is calculated.

Comment: and there was no errors  because the compiler did implicit conversion or promotion or something  like this ?

Comment: @EricPostpischil You have misinterpreted the meaning of "difference" there. It is not the 'subtraction' type of difference. Maybe the answer has to do with *types*.

Comment: @ArdentCoder implicit conversion maybe ? 
but based on what logic .. I can only imagine implicit conversion or promotion  between variables of  primitive data types

Comment: @MohamedAtef Yup, I guess. I'm asking the same to the answerer

Comment: @MohamedAtef The standard does allow converting between pointer types, however in most cases it doesn't make sense to compare them.

Comment: @dbush but how did the build stage occur without errors ? promotion or implicit conversion ?